# Science Fiction book where one of the plot points was jettisoning the science module of a space station because it was built to be modular

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a adventure science fiction YA/MG novel that I read sometime in 2013 or 2014.

This is going to be super vague but I distinctly remember one plot point in the book. The group of characters were aboard a space station, a floating underwater station, or a in-orbit platform (like the helicarrier) that was built for science. I can't exactly remember what kind of station it was. Anyway, a bunch of survivors or random people had to come aboard due to some crisis. Then, due to this crisis, the station was losing power and was going to lose life support. I remember that they went in moderate detail to which modules of the facility were using power and still had power, etc and they realized that the entire science lab part was using too much energy. They jettisoned the Science module into the ocean or into space and this was not a decision that was made lightly, and there was discussion about doing it. They could jettison the module because the station was built to be modular. They removed the module with considerable difficulty and it damaged parts of the space station. After the module was jettisoned, they had enough power to keep surviving until their rescue arrived.

Can somebody please help me in figuring out what this is?
Also, this wasn't the whole book, just the climax, but I remember that the station was a plot point and maybe the setting.

Comment: Did it involve a genetically engineered race with hands for feet and null G adaptations?

Comment: Maybe though I doubt it. I really don't remember the story that well.

Comment: Was there an astronaut who did a solo reentry using an experimental emergency system?

Comment: Did the Moon fall apart?

Comment: Not sure about the experimental system but the moon falling apart does sound vaguely familiar.

Comment: Hmm... my guess was going to be Bujold's *Falling Free*, but further details it doesn't match.

Comment: @Spencer How call the Moon fall apart? Into where?

Comment: The moon falling apart and people escaping on a space station sounds a bit like *Seveneyes* by Neil Stephenson.

Comment: Maybe its part of "The 100" book series? I have never read the series, (Just watched some of the TV show) but I do know the space station was failing and they were shutting down parts of it to survive. *Don't know if they were detaching parts of it.)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Exactly. I was trying to suggest that without being accused of calling 'dibs'.

Comment: Do you remember if it was from a major franchise? There's a YA Star Trek novel, *Atlantis Station*, with a similar plot aboard an undersea station, except that ISTR they took cover in a sealed module and struggled from there to a shuttle to escape.

Comment: It might of actually been Atlantis Station, because that atlantis part does sound really similar.